# Transfer File to executescript NiFi using python

Tags: python, apache-nifi, execute-script

I am trying to use NiFi ExecuteScript to post messages to an irc chatroom using Python. Am I using the right syntax to pass a flowfile from a queue to the processor? Processor errors out with NameError: global name 'server' is not defined, but I am not positive what's causing it. Everything seems to work until I add the session.get().

```
import socket
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import StreamCallback, InputStreamCallback

class PyStreamCallback(InputStreamCallback):
    def __init__(self):
       pass
       self.ircsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
       self.server = "irc.freenode.net"
       self.channel = ""
       self.botnick = ""
       self.ircsock.connect((server, 6667))
       self.ircsock.send(bytes("USER "+ botnick +" "+ botnick +" "+ botnick + " " + botnick + "\n"))
       self.ircsock.send(bytes("NICK "+ botnick +"\n"))

    def joinchan(self, chan):
      self.ircsock.send(bytes("JOIN "+ chan +"\n"))
      ircmsg = ""
      while ircmsg.find("End of /NAMES list.") == -1:
        self.ircmsg = ircsock.recv(2048)
        self.ircmsg = ircmsg.strip('\n\r')
        print(ircmsg)

    def sendmsg(self, msg, target=channel):
      self.ircsock.send(bytes("PRIVMSG "+ target +" :"+ msg +"\n"))



flowFile = session.get()
if (flowFile != None):
  flowFile = session.read(flowFile,PyStreamCallback())
session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.ircsock.connect((server, 6667))
```

should be

```
self.ircsock.connect((self.server, 6667))
```

Comment: the flowfile from the queue is still not getting transferred properly. Am i reading the flowfile in properly?

Comment: Sorry, don't know the flowfile or session. but "flowFile = session.read(flowFile,PyStreamCallback())" this line maybe need to modify to "session.read(flowFile,PyStreamCallback())". Don't set flowfile to the session.read's return value.